# Possible defect: Ability to post answers after having questions closed

Tags: bug, user-interface

**Summary**

I was helping out the asker of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29065783/for-loop-in-python-skips/). I was almost done writing the answer, when I noticed that the "Post Answer" button was disabled. I opened the DOM inspector of Chrome, removed the disabled attribute and went ahead to post it.  It didn't strike me at the moment that the button was disabled out of a genuine reason.

Upon opening the linked question, you will observe that [@inspectorG4dget](https://stackoverflow.com/users/198633/inspectorg4dget) at 2015-03-15 20:29:18Z but I posted my answer at 2015-03-15 20:33:47Z -- much after the question got closed.

What's weird is: I'd expect the Javascript to post the request, but I didn't expect the server to accept it – because [@inspectorG4dget](https://stackoverflow.com/users/198633/inspectorg4dget) had closed it 5 minutes back!

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Visit some question.
2. Start answering.
3. Have someone close it as duplicate (or something)
4. Modify the DOM, so that the submit button does not have the disabled attribute.
5. Hit "Submit" button.
6. !!!

**Reproducibility**

Don't know, really. I do not want to experiment with other questions. Please let me know if there is a way to test this out in isolation without affect the rest of the site or causing noise.

**Question**

Why doesn't SO have server side validation for this situation? Is this a bug?

Comment: This has been discussed before and is status-bydesign.